# Call JS Function with Form Submit Value

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a autocomplete form inputs, I want to call a javascript function with the autocomplete selected value.

I have the form and the JS function, on submit if I give a specific value it's calling the js function. But I didn't get how to pass the value of the form submit to the js function. Here is the code I tried. if you have any idea how to pass the values, please let me know. your help is much appreciated. thanks.

```
<form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:1120px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="country">
  </div>
  <input onclick="filterSelection('all')" type="submit"> <!-- filterSelection() is the JS function, and I am passing value as 'all'. its working. But I want to pass the submit value from the form.
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the current value of the element using `document.getElementById('myInput').value`:

**Demo:**

```js
function filterSelection(v){
  alert(v);
}
```

```html
<form autocomplete="off" action="/action_page.php">
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:1120px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="country">
  </div>
  <input onclick="filterSelection(document.getElementById('myInput').value)" type="submit"> <!-- filterSelection() is the JS function, and I am passing value as 'all'. its working. But I want to pass the submit value from the form.-->
</form>
```